# Bind selected record to grid fro xml sheet

Tags: asp.net

I have a xml sheet in the form of

```
<markers>
  <marker name="abc1" label="xyz" place="mno">
  <marker name="pqr2" label="lmn" place="mno">
  <marker name="abc3" label="xyz" place="mno">
  <marker name="pqr4" label="lmn" place="mno">
  <marker name="abc5" label="xyz" place="mno">
  <marker name="pqr6" label="lmn" place="mno">
</markers>
```

1. I have to bind this xml file to a grid view and with "name" field as linkbutton.
2. Clicking on the linkbutton should display a separate grid displaying only that particular record with edit/delete options.

first part I am able to do successfully with the help of google. But I am unable to do second part. I am very new to programing. Please help me in codding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: y u want separate grid to show/edit selected record?you can do it in same grid

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the xml into a class

```
class Marker
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Label{get;set;}
   public string Place{get;set;} 
}
```

and bind the data to for example a list of Marker objects. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) for how to bind/edit data to an object data source, which allows editing via the gridview control.

Hope this gets you a bit further.